# Sencha touch 2- Ext.dispatch replacement?

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

What is the replacement for sencha touch 1.1 `Ext.dispatch` method in sencha touch 2?

I need replacement for code below

```
listeners:{
    itemtap:function(data,index){
        var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);
         // the record that has been clicked.
         Ext.dispatch({
            controller: 'ControllerName'
            ,action: 'ControllerMethod'
            ,record: record
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151239-Ext.dispatch-replacement

Comment: Btw what has ruby on rails 3 to do with this question? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `Ext.dispatch` still exists in Sencha Touch 2: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-dispatch

But if you just don't like to use it for some reason, you can get an instance of the controller and call method dicrectly:

```
Ext.ControllerManager.get('ControllerName').ControllerMethod({record: record});
```

Comment: ?? The version is even in the link man! it's sencha 1.1 not 2! Check this http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151239-Ext.dispatch-replacement

Comment: My bad, but anyway controllers exists in Sencha 2, they just have another namespace `Ext.app.Controller`. You can call static method `getController` to get an instance of the controller and then call some method from it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

In sencha touch 2.0 to get the controller instances from anywhere use

```
<your app name>.app.getController('your controller name');
```

where your application name is setup in app.js

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it should work:

```
window['AppName'].app.getController('ControllerName').MethodName(Args)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
window['AppName'].app.dispatch({
    controller: 'ControllerName',
    action: 'MethodName',
    args:ArgsArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the call shal be done from a controller, you'll have the application instance by `getApplication` method, there is a method `getControllerInstance` which returns an array.

```
this.getApplication().getControllerInstances()['yourcontrollername'].yourmethod(yourparams)
```