# Facing an issue in hiding the overlay in sencha touch2.0

Tags: android, sencha-touch, overlay, panel, sencha-touch-2

I need to show an overlay on button click.To achieve this i have written the following code:-

```
 var miscButton = {
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'star',
                iconMask: true,
                width: 60,
                margin: '0 0 0 15',
                handler: function(){

                  fPanel.showBy(this);
                }
        };



       var fPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    width: 150,
                    height: 300,
                    style: 'background-color: #5E99CC;',
                    items: [
                            {
                               xtype: 'list',
                               flex: 1,
                               itemTpl: '{item}',
                               data: [
                                          {item: 'item1'},
                                          {item: 'item2'},
                                          {item: 'item3'},
                                          {item: 'item4'},
                                          {item: 'item5'},
                                          {item: 'item6'},
                                          {item: 'item7'},
                                          {item: 'item8'},
                                          {item: 'item9'},
                                          {item: 'item10'},
                                          {item: 'item11'},
                                          {item: 'item12'},
                               ]                    
                            }
                    ]

        });
```

When i click on button it is showing the overlay perfectly but after another click it is not able to hide the overlay,like given in the link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/overlays.

I dont understand what is the problem with showBy(). Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please update your reference link from Sencha docs, it seems mistyped. And btw, what do you mean by "after another click"? please be more specific

Comment: another click means second click.At first click button is showing overlay perfectly but when i again click the button overlay is not hiding.

Comment: have you tried adding this config: `modal: true` to your fPanel?

Comment: No buddy not working need another solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide an overlay panel, simply make a call

```
fPanel.hide();
```

---

FYI, if you want to be able to hide the panel on mask tap, use this property of panel,

```
modal: true,
hideOnMaskTap: true
```

Comment: i know abt this method but dont want to use it becoz if i use it overlay will not hide when i click to other buttons.

Comment: Check the edited answer. May be, you were looking for `hideOnMaskTap`

Comment: `hideOnMaskTap` only works when `modal` config is set to true

Comment: ^ Yes, I know, he may set `modal:true` as well. He wants to hide the overlay on any click, I guess from his question and comment.

Comment: Re-post your latest code. I want to know what have you written

Comment: I knew right from the start, this solution of both setting to true **will** work

Comment: hey roadRunner plz go through the link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205352-How-to-pass-data-among-the-screens-in-sencha-touch2.0 and suggest me something to solve it.

Comment: @ Thiem Nguyen : What happened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580984/how-to-pass-data-among-the-screens-in-sencha-touch2-0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a quite "ugly" work-around but it does work:

```
handler: function(){
  fPanel.setHidden(!fPanel.getHidden());
}
```

There might be some typing mistakes in that snippet but my idea is to toggle your panel's `hidden` property

Comment: modal: true,
hideOnMaskTap: true 

this solution worked buddy thanx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580984/how-to-pass-data-among-the-screens-in-sencha-touch2-0